# How to write query to find out products which visibility is 4 for configurable product but his child product visibility is 1?

Tags: magento2.3.1

I need to help here to get product display only configurable product not his child products.

So here I have one configurable product name ==> Product 1

and his child products such 
Product 1-White-20 
Product 1-White-30 
Product 1-Red-20 
Product 1-Red-30

these all 4 child product visibility 1 .

now ist particular size attribute 
Product 1-White-20(attribute size ==20) 
Product 1-White-30(attribute size ==30) 
Product 1-Red-20 (attribute size ==20)
Product 1-Red-30 (attribute size ==30)

but my main product has not any size selected.

so when I want to filter by size then no products comes in filter result.

So in may main product not a size but in child product there are size attribute so i need to display only main product in filter result.

so please help me.
Thanks in Advance.